# Why are certain variables marked as final in flutter custom classes?

Tags: flutter, variables, dart, final

I noticed in some of the examples online that classes that extend `StatefulWidget` have instance variables marked with final. Why is that?
I understand what the final keyword does. I do not understand why it is being declared with each instance variable that extends the widget class.

Comment: That's very unclear. Do you have an example of what you don't understand ?

Comment: Yes for example https://github.com/putraxor/flutter-login-ui/blob/master/lib/home_page.dart Why are all the variables declared under ```Widget build(BuildContext context)``` marked as final

Comment: Your original question asks something different than what you're describing in the comment. That is a stateless widget.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Because `StatefulWidget` inherits `Widget`, which is marked as `@immutable`, any subclass of `StatefulWidget` must also be immutable (i.e. all fields final).

If you make a `StatefulWidget` subclass with non-final fields, it will result in this Dart analysis warning:

> info: This class inherits from a class marked as @immutable, and
> therefore should be immutable (all instance fields must be final).
> (must_be_immutable at [...] lib....dart:23)

And an explanation of how to use `StatefulWidget` from the [StatefulWidget documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html):

> StatefulWidget instances themselves are immutable and store their
> mutable state either in separate State objects that are created by the
> createState method, or in objects to which that State subscribes, for
> example Stream or ChangeNotifier objects, to which references are
> stored in final fields on the StatefulWidget itself.

Comment: As to the comment in with the link to [home page](https://github.com/putraxor/flutter-login-ui/blob/master/lib/home_page.dart) - that is just the programmer's personal preference as I don't see any actual reason for those variables to be final. I don't believe that's standard.

Answer (score 16):

There's no finite answer to this question. This is more of a preference.

Fact is that if a variable can be declared as `final`, then why *not* declare is as so ? `final` keyword doesn't hurt your code at all and can potentially help catch bugs.

In fact you can even enable a custom linter rule called `prefer_final_locals` which will make compilation fails if you have a non-final variable that is never reassigned.

This allows a double health check : immutable variables won't be able to change. But at the same time, if you forgot to mutate a non-final variable, the compiler will also warn you.

Comment: This answer would apply to most classes that aren't StatefulWidget, but for StatefulWidget there is a direct answer. Also - I recognize that the OP's comment on their question confuses matters a little.

Answer (score 11):

"final" is very similar to "const" in application but different for compile-time reasons: See this [link](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html) or below for further explanation:

**"final"** means single-assignment: a final variable or field *must* have an initializer. Once assigned a value, a final variable's value cannot be changed. final modifies *variables*.

**"const"** has a meaning that's a bit more complex and subtle in Dart. const modifies *values*. You can use it when creating collections, like const [1, 2, 3], and when constructing objects (instead of new) like const Point(2, 3). Here, const means that the object's entire deep state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the object will be frozen and completely immutable.

Comment: "I understand what final keyword does". OP wants answer in context with widgets.

Answer (score -1):

from what I understand from watching the boring show developed by the flutter team. Final and Const are helpful because it helps flutter know that these values wont be updated and therefore the algorithm can figure out what to update more efficiently. If i'm wrong please someone correct me

Answer (score -1):

Why do we use final and what benefits can we get from it.

The core concept of Flutter's three-tree model (widget, element, render) is to avoid complicated computer restart during frame updating. So element and render tree will avoid rebuild, and widget tree as config will frequently be rebuild (widget object will frequently be create).

Therefore, the question is just like creating some object frequently, what kind of design concept are suitable for it. That's an immutable object. Think of the String class of java. The benefit is thread safe (unsafe is to share and mutable variable), no invalid state, more readable and maintainable code.

And if you have some variable state, then you should write that in your state object. The state is saved by an element object.
So the element and render object is the minmum create times, they use state object to corresponding change. The widget is often created, but it is simple and immutable every time. Just like general, make command "turn right, turn left", they never say "turn ri, left".

Finally, you can read this [Why are flutter widgets immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811377/why-are-flutter-widgets-immutable)